# 403 Forbidden with apache and passenger

Tags: apache-2.4, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I am getting sporadic 403 responses from a server running Passenger within Apache. The problem starts on seemingly random occasions, and ends randomly as well. From the log, it seems that Apache is trying to run the url as a script:

```
[Fri Oct 11 17:23:51.509902 2019] [core:trace4] [pid 7309:tid 139735209076480] u
til_script.c(571): [client 132.72.41.107:38416] Headers from script '':
[Fri Oct 11 17:23:51.509934 2019] [core:trace4] [pid 7309:tid 139735209076480] util_script.c(572): [client 132.72.41.107:38416]   Status: 403 Forbidden
[Fri Oct 11 17:23:51.509942 2019] [core:trace1] [pid 7309:tid 139735209076480] util_script.c(653): [client 132.72.41.107:38416] Status line from script '': 403 Forbidden
[Fri Oct 11 17:23:51.509948 2019] [core:trace4] [pid 7309:tid 139735209076480] util_script.c(572): [client 132.72.41.107:38416]   Cache-Control: no-cache
[Fri Oct 11 17:23:51.509954 2019] [core:trace4] [pid 7309:tid 139735209076480] util_script.c(572): [client 132.72.41.107:38416]   Vary: Origin
```

The passenger log file does not contain any relevant information, and neither does the application (rails) log. Static files not served by passenger are served as usual.

The apache config:

```
PassengerLogFile ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/passenger.log
PassengerLogLevel 8

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName math.bgu.ac.il
ServerAlias www.math.bgu.ac.il
ServerSignature off
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
ProxyPreserveHost on

PassengerAppEnv production
PassengerFriendlyErrorPages on
PassengerLoadShellEnvvars off
PassengerMaxRequestQueueSize 300
PassengerUser wwwmath
PassengerGroup www-data
PassengerInstanceRegistryDir /var/run/passenger
DocumentRoot /var/www/math/current/public
DirectoryCheckHandler on

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>                                                         
ProxyPassMatch "^/~(.*)$" "http://user-web1.cs.bgu.ac.il/~$1"                                                                                                 
</IfModule>                                                                    

Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/redirects.include                         

<Directory /var/www/math/current/public>                                       
Allow from all                                                                 
Options -MultiViews                                                            
Require all granted                                                            
</Directory>                                                                   

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>                                                         
<Location /git>                                                                
  PassengerEnabled off                                                         
  Require all granted                                                                                                                  
  Header always set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN                                 
  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8181                                       
  ProxyPassReverse http://www.math.bgu.ac.il/                                  
</Location>                                                                    

  RewriteEngine on                                                             
  #Don't escape encoded characters in api requests                             
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/v4/.*                                       
  RewriteRule ^/git(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8181/git/$1 [P,QSA,NE]                
  #Forward all requests to gitlab-workhorse except existing files like error documents                                                                         
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]                    
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.*                                      
  RewriteRule ^/git(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8181/git/$1 [P,QSA,NE]                

  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]                    
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.*                                      
  RewriteRule ^/mattermost(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8065/$1 [P,QSA,NE]             
</IfModule>                                                                    

# add trailing slash to dirs                                                   
RewriteEngine On                                                               
RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI}" -d                               
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$                                             
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L]                                                     

        LogLevel trace4 rewrite:info                                           

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log                                   
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log vhost_combined                  

</VirtualHost>
```

Output of `passenger-status`:

```
Version : 6.0.4                                                                
Date    : 2019-10-11 17:35:19 +0300                                            
Instance: 6TJeLpUK (Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/6.0.4)

----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 6
App groups    : 1
Processes     : 2
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/var/www/math/current (production):
  App root: /var/www/math/current
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 7569    Sessions: 0       Processed: 62      Uptime: 11m 28s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 165M    Last used: 34s ago
  * PID: 14050   Sessions: 0       Processed: 0       Uptime: 1m 17s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 46M     Last used: 1m 17s ago
```

Will be happy to provide additional info, not sure what's relevant

Comment: Hello. I have the same problem here. Did you find a workaround?

Comment: Yes, I just posted the answer

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: I use `rack-attack' to protect against brute-force attacks, but the requests are forwarded from a proxy, and so all the requests had the ip of the proxy. Unfortunately, I forget how I fixed it...